# Does Everywhere Implies Almost Everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know the concept of 'almost everywhere' in measure theory. For example, $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded almost everywhere means if $B = \{x\in E: f \text{ is not bounded}\}$, then the measure $\mu(B) = 0$. However, I was wondering if $f$ is bounded implies $f$ is bounded almost everywhere. It seems trivially true to me, but I haven't found any discussions related to this. My purpose is to manipulate the measure concept to help with one of my ongoing proofs.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Doesn't $f$ is bounded mean $B=\{x\in E: f \text{ is not bounded}\}=\emptyset$?

Comment: @maciek97x I just thought about this also. So this is the correct logic?

Comment: Welp, if $B=\emptyset$, what's $\mu(B)$?

Comment: It seems trivially true because it is in fact trivially true.

Comment: okay thanks guys...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(To get it off the unanswered question queue:)

If $f$ is everywhere bounded, $B=\emptyset$ so $\mu(B)=0$ and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

The set $B$ in the question does not quite make sense. That is, the set $B=\{x\in E:f\;\hbox{is bounded}\}$ doesn't quite make sense because the condition does not refer to $x$. If we make the obvious change to $\{x:f(x)\;\hbox{is bounded}\}$, then there is still a confusion because $f(x)$ is a number, and every number is "bounded", I think.

Probably what you intend is that almost-everywhere-bounded meanse that there is $0<b\in\mathbb R$ such that $\{x:|f(x)|\ge b\}$ has measure $0$. Well, if $f$ is actually bounded, we can take $b$ to be the sup of values $|f(x)|$, which boundedness promises is finite.